# Textures are stripey after importing obj and mtl

Tags: texturing, obj

I'm using shapenet and after importing my airplanes (from the obj and mtl files), the textures are striped, for some reason.
I've looked into it but cannot find much. Here is an example image:

[image]

Does anybody have a clue on why this is happening/how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: z-buffer fighting? are the insignia geometry on top of the wing? Or some of the tris didn't get texture mapped right

Comment: Most likely there are overlapping faces.